# "Cooking with gas" meanig

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of **cooking with gas** in the following context?

One of my software developer colleauges said this:

> So assuming we have latest Venus, once we have a RateEstimate UiDef
>   present on local, the new Broker in our local Partner Service and a
>   Manifest for that new Broker in the workflow service ... **we should be
>   cooking with gas**

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25897/origin-of-the-phrase-now-were-cooking-with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand it to mean that *things are now progressing well*.

The two ways that people normally cook *in their home* are with electricity, or gas. I'm no expert but the benefits of gas are that the heat is *instant* and *constant*, whereas electric elements take time to warm up and cool down. Gas is therefore considered to be faster and more efficient.

So when someone figuratively says "we're cooking with/on gas now!" it is generally understood to mean that things are progressing, and perhaps quickly.

I notice that it is especially used when perhaps something has had a slow start but now has momentum.

(I am a native British English speaker)

Comment: People also cooked with wood-burning stoves.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo yes they did, but I didn't want to get too side-tracked with the history of the stove.

Comment: You got sidetracked comparing gas to electricity :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I feel one example is useful, two would be a distraction.

Answer (score -2):

It means you are doing just right thing!

So, the person means to say that given the condition, you people will be doing the right thing that would lead to success.

[References are here.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cooking+with+gas)

Another variation is: [cooking on gas.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+cooking+on+gas)